# Modification of an air mass

Tags: meteorology, homework, synoptic

If an air mass that exists in North America starts moving south west or south east what kind of modification will affect it and how would you characterize it in it's final state?

My answer is that it would be a cP or an A air mass that would start moving so firstly it would be dry,cold and stable.During it's south movement it's temperature would decrease because of the latitude and also if it moves over any major lakes it would pick up some moisture.My problem is what happens when it reaches the Pacific ocean or the Atlantic ocean.I know it's moisture would increase but do I need to know if it's winter or summer to conclude if it's stable/unstable and cold/warm?

Is my answer complete?

Comment: what is cP ? It is not clear at all

Comment: @gansub in Physical Geography they often designate air masses via the origin. This designation reflects the humidity and temperature of the air, i.e. cP is a continental air mass coming from polar regions, therefore it is dry and cold. A is a very cold Arctic air mass.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Thank you. So this looks like a homework question if you ask me.

Comment: it is indeed a homework question.Is this not the right place to ask this question?

Comment: @HarryFriedrichGauss As long as you clearly indicate what you have tried and what part you don't understand, asking help with homework questions is perfectly fine.  As stated, your question is fine.